# "The way she went about things" as 彼のする方

Tags: grammar, translation

I'm working to translate this particular line, wondering if it accurately puts across this idea. Alternatives are welcome too!
彼{かれ}のする方{かた}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

「[彼女]{かのじょ}の[物事]{ものごと}**への**[取]{と}り[組]{く}み[方]{かた}」

or

「彼女の物事**の**取り組み方」